# Adding hashtag to files

Tags: awk

I have a awk program add_hashtag.awk

```
BEGIN{printf("#")}1
```

and a bash program

```
for file in *.asc; do awk -f add_hashtag.awk "$file" > "$file"_in; done
```

that add hashtag into file. It works, however, I would like to get files with same names. When I run

```
for file in *.asc; do awk -f add_hashtag.awk "$file" > "$file"; done
```

I get files only with #.
How to do that? Thank you

Comment: `awk -f add_hashtag.awk "$file" > "$file"` will effectively truncate "$file" to zero-length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
for file in *.asc; do awk -f add_hashtag.awk "$file" > "temp_file" && mv "temp_file" "$file"; done
```

I am going with approach where creating a `temp_file` for output and later renaming it to Input_file so that there will not be any danger of losing or truncating actual Input_file. Also it will not rename temp_file to actual Input_file until/unless `awk` command is a success(with use of `&&`)

---

---

With `gawk` 4.1.0 version or so try(haven't tested it since no samples were given):

```
awk -i inplace -f add_hashtag.awk *.asc
```

OR in case you want to inplace edit files along with taking their backup:

```
awk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.backup -f add_hashtag.awk *.asc
```